# Image from programmatic screen capture different from external capture program

Tags: graphics, gdi, screen-capture

I've been temporarily using external programs (like Hypersnap) to capture areas on a form that have some high-chroma line graphics. That was intended as a temporary solution while the program took shape.

Finally got around to doing the captures programmatically from within the (C#) program. Surprise... The higher chroma lines are noticeably subdued.

IOW:

1. I use Hypersnap to capture the graphics that my program is displaying to "HyperSnap1.jpg"
2. I use internal C# capture code to capture the same area to "InternalSnap2.jpg"
3. Now I display both .jpg capture files using another external file viewer.

The HyperSnap1.jpg image looks exactly like the graphics that my program is showing on-screen.
InternalSnap2.jpg looks pretty close but is lower in chroma, especially when the original
image has high chroma red or yellow lines.

OK, so it's got to be the capture code, right?  I've swapped in several different C# capture functions that I've found here and there (Codeproject and elsewhere).  All do the same thing (lower chroma).  So either all those functions have a similar bug (seems unlikely), or there is a trick that Hypersnap is applying.

Is this a known problem?  If so, are there workarounds?

Comment: In your 2nd step, have you tried saving your capture to a non destructive format like bmp? Maybe you jpeg is to much compressed.

Comment: To StephanM: I do believe you are correct about the cause!  I should have thought to check that, but this is rather surprising. Given that the saved areas are monochromatic lines, I wouldn't think that image compression ratio would be improved by diminishing chroma. It's just a single number, after all. The jpg images simply show a lower key red rather than high chroma red. And the default compression ratio must be rather extreme to cause this. Thanks, Stephane.